# Word count jquery and stop user from typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("input").keyup(function(){
         if($(this).val().split(' ').length == 10){
             alert();
         }
  });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="text">
```

If the input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 the alert fired, I know it included the space. But how to stop user from adding more character (even space) when the limit is reached?

Comment: @RGraham I know maxlength but I want to achieve something else using js

Answer (score 1):

The problem can easily be simplified to disabling the spacebar when the max word count is reached:

this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/wznervgz/6/

```
<input data-max-words="10" />
```

js:

```
$('input[data-max-words]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var $txt = $(this),
        max = $txt.data('maxWords'),
        val = $txt.val(),
        words = val.split(' ').length;

    if (words === max && e.keyCode === 32)
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about storing the value of the input after each keyup and if the wordcount is greater than your limit just `setVal` back to the "previously" saved amount.  So it would start off as `var previousVal = '';` and then increment accordingly until the comparison returns true, set the val and return.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wznervgz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var previousValue = '';
     $("input").keydown(function(){
         if($(this).val().split(' ').length >= 10){
             alert();
             $(this).val(previousVal);
             return;
         }
         previousVal = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Comment: @AmyJohnson I did forget to add the `val` back originally but edited.

Comment: Your solution does not work if user keeps pressing the spacebar. It still accepts new characters.

Comment: @ArinCool yes, you are correct I have amended the event for keydown instead and amended the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
  <textarea name="txtMsg" id="word_count" cols="1" rows="1"> </textarea>
 <span style="padding-left:10px;">Total word Count : 
 <span id="display_count" style="font-size:16px; color:black;">0</span> words &
<span id="count_left" style="font-size:16px; color:black;">2</span> words left.</span>
<br>
```

jquery code:

```
  var max_count = 2;
 $(document).ready(function () {
var wordCounts = {};
$("#word_count").keyup(function () {
    var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
    wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
    var finalCount = 0;
    $.each(wordCounts, function (k, v) {
        finalCount += v;
    });
    var vl = this.value;
    if (finalCount > max_count) {
        vl = vl.substring(0, vl.length - 1);
        this.value = vl;
    }
    var countleft = parseInt(max_count - finalCount);

    $('#display_count').html(finalCount);
    $('#count_left').html(countleft);
    am_cal(finalCount);
});
}).keyup();
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/aVd4H/32/

Thank you.

Comment: I am able to copy and paste more than the max_count

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
         if($(this).val().split(' ').length == 10){
             alert();
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
}
```